# Logging user in after user have registered

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am reading an article about using passport-local-mongoose for authentication. [Article](https://mherman.org/blog/user-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/)

In this article I found this line of code that do register the user and log them in

```js
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
            return res.render('register', { account : account });
        }

        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
          res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
  });
```

And the part that confuse me is this

```js
passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

First, I don't understand the part that go after `passport.authenticate()`. It doesn't look like a callback or IIFE. 
Second, as far as I know, `passport.authenticate()` is a middleware (sorry if I'm wrong). Should we use it as a function like that.

My best explanation for this is because in the article have defined above

`passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()))`

Because of that, `passport.authenticate()` now will call `Account.authenticate()`. The strange part is, `authenticate()` require a password, which we didn't provide it any. Maybe it return a Promise, but the part I said above doesn't look like a Promise.

So what is that part is, and is it a good practice to actually sign a user in?

Comment: A middleware is a function with the signature (req, res, next) so, passport.authenticate return a function (req, res, next), so the part that confuse you is just that he call the passport.authenticate which return a middleware which is call with the next argument as a function. I don't know if it is a good practice.

Comment: @ocheriaf are you sure that `passport.authenticate()` return a middleware? I know that `passport.authenticate()` is a middleware, but what does it return is depend on what do we call define on `passport.use()`, which in this case, doesn't do so

Comment: @hunquan Yes, i'm sure, but if you want to be sure, you can go explore the source code : [Here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js) 
Furthermore, an express middleware is a function, if passport.authenticate was a middleware which was called in the route declaration, then the middleware is called only one time at the launch, which is absurd because we want to call it every time a user try to login

Comment: @ocheriaf you are right in passport document they primarily use `passport.authenticate()` as a middleware, and I haven't seen they use it as a function. Turn out that method can be both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets talk about that weird part first:

**TLDR:** As the first commenter mentioned ***passport.authenticate return a function***.

How do we call a function? Like this: `functionName(param1, param2, callbackMaybe);`
. You see no problem with that right?

Now, take a look at the code below

```
function a() {
  return function b() {
    console.log("Hi there!");
  }
}
```

Function `a` returning function `b`. How would you the the `Hi there!` in your console? You have to do it like this `a()()`.
You can se it in this way:

```
let b = a(); // Since, a returns a function so, b is now a function.
b();
```

Same here, `passport.authenticate('local')` returning a function that takes 3 parameters where last one is a callback function. In terms of express the 3rd parameter is the `next()` function. I believe you know the usage of `next()` function. You are sending `function () { res.redirect('/'); }` as a callback. What this callback does it redirect you to this `'/'` route.

**Second part of your question**

Now a days, I do not see any website auto login user after signing up.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So the `next()`  function only mean to be used in Express - like for passing error to next matching route? Is using a middleware outside from its normal place - "middleware" as a normal function changing the meaning of `next()`?

Comment: When you send error to the next function it does not pass it to the next route, it takes you to the error handler. I am not sure what you exactly mean by the second line but, if you have access to the `next()` function (it doesn't matter where) then you can use it.